Add header for requests to particular domains for browser in Windows kiosk mode to supply auth token
Is there any built-in way to provide headers to add to requests for a particular domain in Edge? Or Chrome - or any browser that can be used with Windows Kiosk mode?
I need to authenticate the machine with a web service that it runs automatically. Mutual certificates would be best (and I know that is built-in) but the service runs behind a CDN that doesn't support client certificates. Adding a token header would be the simplest path forward but it doesn't appear that the browsers I've looked at offer this feature?
